# React: setState after a graphQL request

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I've been searching for a couple of hours now, but just can't seem to find the answer. See my code below. I'm requesting some metro-information to be used on an info-screen.
I'm getting the information, seeing as console.log works. However I'm having difficulty using this resulting oject. I want to use the data received, so that I can display when the next train arives. To this purpose I try to setState with the result, so that I can access the data-elements further down. However, now I'm stuck at setState giving me problems. I feel that I need to bind the function, but `this.main = this.main.bind(this)` doesn't work.

```
import React from "react";
import { GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";

class Rutetider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stoppestedet: "rutetider lastes ned"
    };

    async function main() {
      const endpoint = "https://api.entur.org/journeyplanner/2.0/index/graphql";

      const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
        headers: {
          ET: "lossfelt-tavle"
        }
      });

      const query = `
    {
  stopPlace(id: "NSR:StopPlace:58249") {
    id
    name
    estimatedCalls(timeRange: 3600, numberOfDepartures: 20) {     
      realtime
      aimedArrivalTime
      aimedDepartureTime
      expectedArrivalTime
      expectedDepartureTime
      actualArrivalTime
      actualDepartureTime
      cancellation
      notices {
        text
      }
      situations {
        summary {
          value
        }
      }
      date
      forBoarding
      forAlighting
      destinationDisplay {
        frontText
      }
      quay {
        id
      }
      serviceJourney {
        journeyPattern {
          line {
            id
            name
            transportMode
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  `;

      const data = await graphQLClient.request(query);
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ stoppestedet: data.stopPlace.name });
    }

    main().catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        rutetider
        <div className="grid-container2">
          <div>Mot byen</div>
          <div>fra byen</div>
          <div>{this.state.stoppestedet}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Rutetider;
```

Comment: it's not clear what your problem is, please clarify: what sort of problems is setState giving you?

Comment: `main` is inside constructor - define it in class/object scope, call from `componentDidMount` with `this.main()...`

Comment: @AlekseyBykov I get the error that it is undefined.

Comment: @xadm Thanks for the suggestion. I tried doing as you suggested, moving the definition of `main` outside of the constructor, and then calling it from componentDidMount. However now I instead get errors on the Main-function like this: 

`SyntaxError
/src/rutetider.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (13:17)

  11 |   }
  12 |  
> 13 |   async function main() {
     |                 ^
  14 |       const endpoint = "https://api.entur.org/journeyplanner/2.0/index/graphql";
  15 | 
  16 |       const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {`

Comment: @xadm probably easier to just link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wkq28n5o6l

Answer (score 0):

"probably easier" is to use integrated solution (apollo) than minimal, low level library. In most cases (as project grows), with more components fetching data managing separate `GraphQLClient` for all of them won't be an optimal solution. Apollo gives you centralised "fetching point", cache .. and many more.

Syntax error comes from `function` - in `class` it's enough to write `async main()`

https://codesandbox.io/s/l25r2kol7q

It probably would be better to save entire data in state and extract needed parts later (at `render`) and use this object as 'data-ready flag' (as I did for place - 'stoppestedet') - initally `undefined` (in constructor) for initial render (conditional rendering, some `<Loading />` component):

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.stoppestedet) return "rutetider lastes ned";
  return (
    <div>
      rutetider
      <div className="grid-container2">
        <div>Mot byen</div>
        <div>fra byen</div>
        <div>{this.renderFetchedDataTable()}</div>
      </div>
```